# wxpython - How to refresh listbox from outside of class?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

```
class ListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ListCtrl, self).__init__(parent,size=(1200,700))

    def delete_items(self):
        self.DeleteAllItems()

class One(wx.Panel):
    b =wx.Button()
    b.bind(**Listbox.delete_items**)


class Two(wx.Panel):
    self.lb = Listbox(self)
```

1. *In my application, I have two panels.. class One represents the sidebar panel which contains buttons. Class Two represents the main panel which contains the listbox.
2. How do I call a function via a button (in this case to delete items from a listbox ) whose parent belongs to another class (Two)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way you could do this is with pub sub

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher
pub = Publisher()
all_options = "One Two Three".split()
class One(wx.Panel):
     def on_delete_button(self,evt):
         all_options.pop(0)
         pub.sendMessage("update.options",

class Two(wx.Panel):
     def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.lb = Listbox(self)
        self.lb.SetItems(all_options)
        pub.subscribe("update.options",lambda e:self.lb.SetItems(e.data))
```

that said there are many many ways to accomplish this

Comment: Yes, but pubsub is probably the best way...or one of the cleanest anyway

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had to use "from wx.lib.pubsub import setuparg1" and "from wx.lib.pubsub import pub" to avoid import error.